# Joi Validation- Validate array even if only one element matches schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

I would like to validate an array of objects.
And joi should validate the whole array even if only one array element matches schema and reject only if all elements don't match the schema
for exmaple:
schema:

```
Joi.object({
  data: Joi.array()
    .items(Joi.object({a: Joi.number(), b: Joi.string()})) 
})
```

This must pass joi validation:
`[{a:23, b: "Ddd"}, {a:23, b: 34}]`

Only one array element validation should be enough to pass the array validation.

This must not pass validation:

`[{a:23, b: 23}, {a:23, b: 34}]`

Above all elements of the array fails the validation , hence array validation also fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to solve my problem by using stripUnknown option.

```
Joi.object({
  data: Joi.array()
    .items(Joi.object({a: Joi.number(), b: Joi.string()}))
    .options({ stripUnknown: { arrays: true } })
})
```

Above code strips invalid array elements and throws error if no elements passes validation if schema has required.